# JSON Schema - nested property is required based on conditional

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, pydantic, python-dataclasses

I tried to create a minimum viable example for this. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. if json contains `post`, then make both `a` and `b` required in `attrs`
2. if json contains `patch` then make neither of them required.
3. Use `datamodel-codegen` to generate pydantic dataclasses based on this schema.

I believe that there is a way to validate by doing the following, however **I can't do it this way.** For some reason the model generator being used does not properly set the dataclass properties to required/optional when defined this way.

```
"attrs": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/a"
        },
        "b": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/b"
        }
    }
},
"create": {
    "attrs": {
        "$ref": "#/$defs/attrs",
        "required": ["a", "b"]
    }
}
```

leads to

```
class A(BaseModel):
    __root__: str


class B(BaseModel):
    __root__: str


class Attrs(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

    a: Optional[A] = None
    b: Optional[B] = None


class Create(BaseModel):
    attrs: Attrs


class Update(BaseModel):
    attrs: Optional[Attrs] = None


class Model(BaseModel):
    patch: Optional[Update] = None
    post: Optional[Create] = None
```

This is actually incorrect because it implies that each individual attribute is optional. I assume this is because of where in the schema I defined the `required` property.

Instead, I would like to see if there is a way to define the required and optional properties in the definition of `attrs` in the json schema.

This is the schema I made as a template as an example. I tried using `if` and `then` conditions but I couldn't figure it out.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "patch": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/update"
        },
        "post": {
            "$ref": "#/$defs/create"
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "create": {
            "properties": {
                "attrs": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/attrs"
                }
            }
        },
        "update": {
            "properties": {
                "attrs": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/attrs"
                }
            }
        },
        "attrs": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "a": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/a"
                },
                "b": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/b"
                }
            }
        },
        "a": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "b": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I define the required properties of `attrs` based on the conditional, that being that the top level property contains `post` or `patch`?

Comment: What schema version are you using (see `$schema`)?  The answer may shed light on what's going on.  If you're using something before 2020-12 (latest) then using `$ref` alongside other keywords ignores those other keywords.  Try wrapping the `$ref` in an `allOf` if you're using an earlier version.

Comment: Interesting. It may be the case that the package being used to generate the models itself may  not be using the most updated schema. I'll check that out and try wrapping the ref as you say. I assume you mean wrapping both `$ref` and `required` inside of the `allOf`?

Comment: No, just wrap the `$ref` in the `allOf`.  The `required` should be a sibling of `allOf`.  Wrapping both has the same problem.